# PAM LDAP pam_ldap.so: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: vsftpd, ldap, pam

Im trying to get VSFTPD to work with LDAP using PAM. (since it does not sleep with SASL)

If I login into FTP with a Shell credentails it works fine, but when I try to use an LDAP creds to login via ftp then in `/var/log/auth.log` I see:

```
Apr 11 12:50:30 localhost vsftpd: 
PAM unable to dlopen(/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_ldap.so):
libgmp.so.10: failed to map segment from shared object: 
Cannot allocate memory
```

I've tried to lookup threads and a lot of ones that show "Cannot allocate memory" are unanswered or inconclusive. Please help.

My configs are:

```
$ cat /etc/pam.d/vsftpd
auth    required        pam_listfile.so item=user sense=deny file=/etc/ftpusers onerr=succeed

# Standard pam includes
@include common-account
@include common-session
@include common-auth
auth sufficient pam_shells.so

# Additional LDAP configs. Providing absolute path coz PAM searches in /lib/security/..
auth required /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security/pam_ldap.so
```

`ulimit -a` gives:

```
root@localhost:/etc/pam.d# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 3946
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 3946
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Comment: Unrelated: PAM should have no trouble looking in `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/security`. My `common-auth` contains  `pam_ldap.so` and works just fine.

Comment: I agree thats why I mentioned it there in the comment, I found that strange. But when I did not specify the absolute path I got another error saying it could not open /lib/security/pam_ldap.so. So I'm going with what works.

Comment: "what works" - it doesn't, though . Both might be symptoms of the same problem. Which pam ldap library are you using? `libpam-ldap` or `libpam-ldapd`?

Comment: I did an **apt-get install libpam-ldap nscd** So I assume libpam-ldap

Comment: @muru : I managed to fix the immediate issue but yet the absolute path is required. So its unrelated but thanks for pointing it out. Its still worth looking into why this is also happening. Also your question on which pam lib I was using just prompted me to reinstall .. which worked.

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled libpam-ldap

```
sudo apt-get purge libpam-ldap
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get install libpam-ldapd
```

The memory error went away. Now I get a

```
pam_ldap(dovecot:auth): error reading from nslcd: Connection reset by peer
```

but that's obviously dovecot related and a separate issue.

Comment: One thing I want to add is that, for the modules that fail in PAM there is a suspicious corelation with PAM not finding the module in **/lib/security** and having to specify the absolute path. I have found using **pam-auth-update** to configure it fixes things and also does not require one to specify the absolute path of the package. This was also raised my muru in my conversation with him in the comments in the Question section. ... so while I cant provide any technical insght, if you have to specify an absolute path to get it to work .. chances are its the wrong way!